# Is it possible to place <option> tags with CSS next to each other?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have a form like the following:

```
<form action="file.php" method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" name="page">
     <select>
       <option>Text 1</option>
       <option>Text 2</option>
       <option>Text 3</option>
     </select>
  <input type="submit">
```

Is it possible to style this piece of HTML with CSS so that the three option tags don't appear in a drop down but next to each other? Like when making elemens float?

Comment: You can make a column with `<select size="3">` but if you want more control than that you're going to need to use `<label><input type="radio" /> Text</label>` or similar.

Comment: I agree with @NiettheDarkAbsol, why don't you use `type="radio"`? You can hide the radio buttons and style a `label` to make it look however you want. If you want a solution like that, let me know and I'll give you one.

Comment: Why are you trying to force an element to look different rather than just using an element that makes sense like a div?

Comment: Something like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXvqMN lemme know if you'd like that as an answer.

Comment: You know, I don't have to do it this way, but nevertheless I was curious whether there is a neat way you could do it. Apparently there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, this is not possible as far as I know. HTML `<select>`'s are very hard to style, and HTML `<option>`'s are (to my knowledge) impossible to style, unless you use the built in attributes (which still don't always provide exactly what you need).

On the other hand, you could use another element like a `<div>` (as mentioned in the comments).